# SQL Where, LIKE , OR combination issue with Blank textBox

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have this below query

```
SELECT FullUrl
    ,Title
    ,NextWebGroupId
    ,TimeCreated
FROM AllWebsTest
WHERE (Title LIKE '%' + @Title + '%')
    OR (FullUrl LIKE '%' + @FullUrl + '%')
```

Title and FullURL are parameter through TextBox.

What I expect is,

1. If I put text in Title textbox and search, it doesnt give any result, only if I put some string or even blank space in FullURL textbox, only then I get result.
2. Vice versa- if Title is blank (No space as well) and I put search term in fullurl textbox i dont get any result.

How can i handle blank textbox, so that only putting search term in one of the box should return result.

This works fine, if i do query in SQL server directly. But through asp.net webform, its giving problem.

**Update1:** I tried below solutions, while logically it should work i am still not getting results if one of the textbox is untouched. can there be issue with special character? Below is the exact tag

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT FullUrl, Title, NextWebGroupId, TimeCreated FROM AllWebsTest WHERE (Title LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Title, '') + '%') OR (FullUrl LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@FullUrl, '') + '%')">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" Name="Title" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Textsearch2" Name="FullUrl" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Try using SQL Server Profiler to see exactly what query is being sent from the application and executed on the server. Then we could backtrack from that and make the correction, if it is required..

Comment: I ended up putting query is aspx.cs file instead of direct <Asp:gridview control, as there was no way to debug/check the query. Through cs file its working as expected. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for informing us of your final solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT FullUrl
    ,Title
    ,NextWebGroupId
    ,TimeCreated
FROM AllWebsTest
WHERE (Title LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Title, '') + '%')
    AND (FullUrl LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@FullUrl, '') + '%')
```

Take a look at this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce9ad/7) and confirm that this behaviour is what you expected.

This query will filter rows only when a value is passed to one of your variables, `@title` or `@fullURL` (and return those that match the condition). Otherwise it will return all results.

**Update after your recent comments:**

```
SELECT FullUrl
    ,Title
    ,NextWebGroupId
    ,TimeCreated
FROM AllWebsTest
WHERE (Title LIKE '%' + ISNULL(LTRIM(@Title), '') + '%')
    AND (FullUrl LIKE '%' + ISNULL(LTRIM(@FullUrl), '') + '%')
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce9ad/20) with how the code above works.

Comment: Tried this, but still no results with single box search term. Please see updated question.

Comment: @Rohit This exact same query? With `AND` instead of `OR` between the two conditions of the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: yes..thats the exact behavior expected. But putting AND is doing AND if text matches from both boxes then returning result, else blank. Really not sure, why its not working for me. It works fine with single textbox

Comment: As opposed to `OR` between the two conditions of your `WHERE` clause, the `AND` will make it work correctly when you specify values for both variables. But applying `ISNULL` to the variables will also generate a `OR` effect for the query, so you won't be losing this case.

Comment: I think i might have found the issue, so textbox is returning empty string and we are checking for null value. even tested your fiddle with empty string,it doesnt work with that. So same above requirment but with empty string..can there be any single statment for handling all combinations?

Comment: @Rohit If it is returning an empty string, then is it trimmed (no spaces?) or not? That will have a negative effect on the query, but that can be handled in the SQL part as well with an `LTRIM()` function applied to the variable.

Comment: ya..no spaces just this => ''..will you be able to modify the fiddle to handle this, instead of null?

Comment: @Rohit Already adjusted my answer and added a fiddle to see the results.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely something along the way is using `NULL` instead of an empty string, resulting in a `WHERE Title LIKE NULL` which will fail. Try the following instead, explicitly checking for the null case:

```
SELECT FullUrl, Title, NextWebGroupId, TimeCreated
FROM AllWebsTest 
WHERE (@Title IS NULL OR Title LIKE '%' + @Title + '%')
OR (@FullUrl IS NULL OR FullUrl LIKE '%' +  @FullUrl + '%')
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will filter anything since if you don't pass a value to one of the two variables, let's say you pass only a value for `@title`, then the `OR (@FullURL IS NULL OR ... )` will always be true, hence returning all rows ( [example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce9ad/11) )

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Create proc search
 @Title varchar(20) = null,
@FullUrl varchar(20)=  null, 
as
begin
 SELECT FullUrl
    ,Title
    ,NextWebGroupId
    ,TimeCreated
FROM AllWebsTest
WHERE (@Title = null or Title LIKE '%' + @Title + '%')
    OR (@FullUrl = null or FullUrl LIKE '%' + @FullUrl + '%') 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking along with the title, if the string passed is null or empty.

```
SELECT FullUrl
    ,Title
    ,NextWebGroupId
    ,TimeCreated
FROM AllWebsTest
WHERE ( ISNULL(@Title,'') != '' AND Title LIKE '%' + @Title + '%')
    OR (ISNULL(@FullUrl,'') != '' AND FullUrl LIKE '%' + @FullUrl + '%')
```